# How to make radial CCProgressTimer reveal a sprite

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

By default, it appears that a radial CCProgressTimer starts by displaying its entire sprite and removes a portion of the sprite in counterclockwise fashion.

Is there a way to have the timer begin by displaying nothing and display more and more of the sprite as the timer progresses to completion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Start with percentage = 100 and count down to 0.

Comment: It's often the simple things ... ;)